# I'm experiencing a long response time in posting data in postman api

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I send a request in postman api, the application freezes or is stuck on the Sending Request screen.And it is unable to post data.
Can anyone helps me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate and if possible help us with the request that's getting stuck and what that request does.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are debugging your nodejs server and it's caught on a breakpoint. If so, the response will hang. To fix it, just disable that breakpoint, restart your nodejs server, and issue the request again with Postman.

Comment: But I didn't add any breakpoint, one week back I posted the data but now when I am trying to post data it is taking a long response. I am not able to find the error